# Find the number of occurrences of a particular character like comma in a string using ant script?

Tags: ant

```
<project>
<target name="test">
<property name="src.dir" value="src" />
<property name="search4" value=","/>
<fileset id="existing" dir="${src.dir}/src">
    <patternset id="files">
    <include name="*.txt"/>
    </patternset>
</fileset>
<resourcecount property="count">
    <fileset id="matches" dir="../src">
    <patternset refid="files" />
    <contains text="${search4}" />
    </fileset>
</resourcecount>
<echo message="Found '${search4}' in files : '${count}'"/>
</target>
</project>
```

I used this, but this only prints the first occurrence. I would like to print the total count.

For eg - **abc,xyz,pg-**-> The number of occurrences of **commas(,) is 2**.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here. It looks like you're counting the total number of commas in the filenames of all .txt files located in `../src`. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I would like to calculate the number of commas in a particular file inside ../src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way.  Copies the file to another file, with a filter to remove all non-commas, then gets the size of the output, which is the number of commas in the input file.

```
<delete file="out.txt" />
<copy file="in.txt" tofile="out.txt">
  <filterchain>
    <striplinebreaks />
    <replaceregex pattern="[^,]" replace="" flags="gm" />
  </filterchain>
</copy>
<length file="out.txt" property="out.size" />
<echo message="Commas found: ${out.size}" />
```

On your follow up question: how to restrict this to just the first line of the file: add this before the "striplinebreaks" line:

```
    <headfilter lines="1" />
```

That will count commas in just the first line of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Can you please clarify this alone?
For eg, in a file if I have like this:
a,b,c
/next line/ d,e
/next line/ f,g,h
... and so on.
Is it possible to calculate the number of commas in the first line alone?

Comment: See my update - fairly easy change.  If the answer works for you, please mark as accepted/upvote so that people can see the question is answered!